# Верно ли согласование в предложении?

Tags: согласование

> «Понятно, что одной сотой генома, которая нас различает, достаточно...»

Comment: flossyU, всё-таки многоточие — это три точки (а не две). И ещё такая тонкость: если перед кавычками стоит какой-то знак, после них ***такой же*** не принято ставить.

Comment: извините...набираю на скорую руку)

Answer (score 1):

> «Понятно, что **одной сотой** генома, **которая** нас различает,
>   достаточно...»

Автор хотел сказать, что **нас различает всего один ген**, который является одной сотой частью генома, всё верно.

Если бы было другое согласование:

*«Понятно, что одной сотой **генома**, **который** нас различает, достаточно...»*, смысл был бы фактической ошибкой. Геном - совокупность всех генов организма; его полный хромосомный набор. **Геном** - то, чем отличается человек как вид от, например, обезьяны, **но не то, что различает человеческие особи.**

Answer (score 0):

Да, всё верно. Достаточно (чего?) ***одной сотой*** генома (род. падеж).